# Laravel, delete a queue job by user id

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-queue

Each time a user is created or updated, an email will be send when some timestamp is reached.

I control this by queues. Each queue is stored in the "jobs" table.

That table has a column called "payload" which is a json with all the info of that job. In my case, a payload of this is like this one:

```
{  
   "job":"Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call",
   "data":{  
      "commandName":"Illuminate\\Mail\\SendQueuedMailable",
      "command":"O:34:\"Illuminate\\Mail\\SendQueuedMailable\":1:{s:11:\"\u0000*\u0000mailable\";O:16:\"App\\Mail\\Expired\":16:{s:7:\"\u0000*\u0000user\";O:45:\"Illuminate\\Contracts\\Database\\ModelIdentifier\":2:{s:5:\"class\";s:8:\"App\\User\";s:2:\"id\";i:1020;}s:4:\"from\";a:0:{}s:2:\"to\";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:7:\"address\";s:24:\" example@gmail.com\"\";s:4:\"name\";N;}}s:2:\"cc\";a:0:{}s:3:\"bcc\";a:0:{}s:7:\"replyTo\";a:0:{}s:7:\"subject\";N;s:4:\"view\";N;s:8:\"textView\";N;s:8:\"viewData\";a:0:{}s:11:\"attachments\";a:0:{}s:14:\"rawAttachments\";a:0:{}s:9:\"callbacks\";a:0:{}s:10:\"connection\";N;s:5:\"queue\";N;s:5:\"delay\";N;}}"
   }
}
```

As you can see, there job is associated with: `App\\User\";s:2:\"id\";i:1020`

How could I remove that job from the table, by that user id? I could get all the data with `DB::table('jobs)` and loop until I found the id inside `payload` and delete it, but is there any helper or function of Laravel to do that?

Comment: There's no helper function for it, in part because some queue engines don't let you do this at all. You may be better off with a change in approach - have your job check whether it should continue as part of the code. For example, it could check if a user has been deleted and skip the email sending.

Comment: When I update a user, that timestamp could be also updated (is "time trial date" in the future). Each time that timetrial is reached a mail is sent, but I have to remove the job associated to the old timestamp, because I don't want to send email for each time that that timestamp is reached.

Comment: Maybe you need a scheduled task that goes "who should I send to *right now*" instead of a queued job, then.

Comment: The emails that will receive the notification could also me updated, or also every could be removed, I don't know how to do that with schedulling.

Answer (score 2):

You can json_decode the payload and unserialize the $payload['data']['command']

```
    $job = DB::table('jobs')->whereId($id)->first();
    $payload = json_decode($job->payload);
    $mailable = unserialize($payload['data']['command']);
    if ($mailable->user->id != GOOD)
        DB::table('jobs')->whereId($id)->delete();
```

hope this helps

Comment: i got `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` at `$mailable = unserialize($payload['data']['command']);`

Comment: Thanks, but I had to use `$mailable = $payload->data->command` I think I will use this